# How to print the latest kernel version from grub.conf on Linux 7

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, grub

On Linux 5 and 6 I can print the `/etc/grub.conf`

How to verify the latest kernel version on Linux 7? , like we do on Linux 5 and 6 from `grub.conf`

```
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=15
#splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
serial --unit=0 --speed=115200 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1
terminal --timeout=10 serial console

title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.17-1.2519.4.21.el5xen)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /xen.gz-2.6.17-1.2519.4.21.el5 com1=115200,8n1 dom0_mem=256MB
module /vmlinuz-2.6.17-1.2519.4.21.el5xen ro
root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
module /initrd-2.6.17-1.2519.4.21.el5xen.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example `ls /boot/config-*` will print you all the installed kernel versions. But there will be a lot more possibilities how to achieve the same.

`yum info 'kernel*'` should do the job too on all the RHEL's

Comment: is it possible to get from yum command latest kernel version that will be diff from the kernel that I will get from uname -r?

Comment: I don't think so. `yum` knows installed packages, but does not know what kernel are you actually running